# How did Gordon's wristwatch get in his office?

Tags: plot-explanation, halt-and-catch-fire

In *Halt and Catch Fire* S4E09 Joe and Cameron are sitting in Comet office and they hear beeps. Joe explains that it is the alarm on Gordon's wristwatch coming from his office, adding that he doesn't know where the key to the office is.

There seems to be a contradiction.

> In the last scene where Gordon is seen alive in the Comet office before dying, we can see him wearing his wristwatch just before leaving:

[image]
Gordon would have to go out of his way to leave it there as he was in a hurry to meet Haley.

So, how and why did the wristwatch get into Gordon's office?

Comment: @Napoleon Wilson♦ why add HCF in body if it is already in tags?

Comment: Because it's good for questions to be self-contained and provide sufficient context. In the same way we shouldn't answer question titles alone, we also shouldn't rely on tags to provide a question's full context.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson so the title should contain HCF as well?

Comment: No, since it's already in the tags and the question body. The question title and tags don't really have the same responsibility for providing all the necessary context as the body, because they usually can't anyway.

Comment: Gordon was a pretty methodical man — I wouldn't discard the possibility that going to his office and locking it was part of his routine. Not sure why he'd leave the watch there, though. Maybe he didn't take it home ever? Is he wearing it at the actual moment of his death?

Comment: @JNat It's hard to see at the moment of his death because he's got long sleeves, plus it is all in his head anyway, so I wouldn't rely on it too much.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps he had more than one wristwatch.  In the time period in which this is set, if a wristwatch had an alarm at all, it typically had only one setting and it would go off at the same time everyday.  Some digital watches had more than one alarm but they were rare.  All in all, not terribly convenient as a medication reminder unless one only takes medication one time a day.  So, he might have had multiple watches for different alarms.

Comment: Can you edit the answer to sound more affirmative?

Comment: By "affirmative" do you mean conclusive, as if it is the only answer? I suppose I could do that but can you tell me why that is important? It is a speculative answer. Nothing in the episode gave an answer so I supplied one which is plausible, reasonable and consistent with what's onscreen, but it can't be proven true. Why shouldn't speculation sound like speculation?

Comment: Because "could be" is not an answer, it sounds more like a comment, it doesn't sound like you're committing to it.

Comment: Because the author accepts and Acknowledges that there may be a myriad of equally plausible answers to the question so presenting one piece of speculation as if it supersedes all others is arrogant and unseemly.